# Datagridview Checkbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I do really need in this code, I maybe missing something or my solution is just no way near.

I have a datagrid bounded to a DATATABLE and with that im trying to insert a checkbox, what Im trying to accomplish is to set ALL the checkbox to "checked" state. BTW im using mySQL so i think i dont have an option to use BOOLEAN type (true = checked state when it comes to datagrid). Here is my code. Any help is appreciated, TIA.

```
            With dgvPrivilege

            dim dt as new Datatable

            .Datasource = dt '(already had the tables rows ("SELECT pk_id, 
                      access_description as 'Privilege Description' FROM tbl_access_list"))

            Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()

            checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = ""
            checkBoxColumn.Width = 50
            checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
            .Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn)
            .Columns(2).ReadOnly = True



                        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dgvPrivilege.Rows
                            Dim cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = row.Cells(0)
                            cell.Value = True
                        Next

            End with
```

Comment: With MySQL, define the boolean column as `tinyint`, then add this to your connection string:  `treattinyasboolean=True;`.  Then you wont have to create the checkbox columns

Comment: @wysiwyg327 `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` should be `DataGridViewCell`. But, since you have already defined `row`, you can just set the cell for that row: `row.Cells(0).Value = True`. Also, if you don't need boolean results, define the properties `FalseValue` and `TrueValue` of that column to, say, 0 and 1 as their underlying values.